# The Device does not show the text view components while they are visible or present in android studio ide

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed a simple app by watching the newboston tutorial for sql lite database however the problem in it is that in my android studio ide the user interface has two text view components in addition to other components but when I run the application on a physical device the app does not show any text view. I have tested it on two separate devices. Please Help !!

the layout code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.sudhanshu.sqlliteexample.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sudsInput"
            android:width="300dp"
            android:height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:text="Input" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sudsInput"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sudsInput"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sudsInput"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:onClick="addButtonClicked" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DELETE"
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:onClick="deleteButtonClicked"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sudsInput"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sudsInput" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/sudsText"
            android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:height="50dp"
            android:width="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:text="Display" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and the classes involved in it are :
1) MainActivity class

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView sudsInput;
    TextView sudsText;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sudsInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sudsInput);
        sudsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sudsText);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
        printDatabase();
    }

    // ADD A PRODUCT TO THE DATABASE
    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        Products product = new Products(sudsInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addProduct(product);
        printDatabase();
    }

    //DELETE A PROUCT FROM THE DATABASE
    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
        String inputtext =  sudsInput.getText().toString();
        dbHandler.deleteProduct(inputtext);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        sudsText.setText(dbString);
        sudsInput.setText("");
    }

}
```

2)MyDBHandler

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.ContentValues;

    public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
        public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

        public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory,DATABASE_VERSION );
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " + ");";
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        }

        //ADD A NEW ROW TO DATABASE
        public void addProduct(Products product){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME,product.get_productname());
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
            sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS,null,values);
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        }

        //DELETE A PRODUCT FROM THE DATABASE
        public void deleteProduct(String productName){
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("Delete from "+TABLE_PRODUCTS+" where "+ COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME +" =\" " + productName + " \";" );
        }

        // PRINT OUT THE DATABASE AS A STRING
        public String databaseToString(){
            String dbString = "";
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " ;";

            //Cursor points to a location in your results
            Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
            //Move to the first row in your results
            c.moveToFirst();

            while(!c.isAfterLast()){
                if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"))!=null){
                    dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
                    dbString += "\n";
                }
            }
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
            return dbString;

        }
    }
```

3) Products

```
public class Products {
    private int _id;
    private String _productname;

    public Products()
    {
    }

    public Products(String productname) {
        this._productname = productname;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void set_productname(String _productname) {
        this._productname = _productname;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_productname() {
        return _productname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your layouts and UI code so that we could help you

Comment: Added. Please help me now.

Comment: Have you tried debugging at your `printDatabase` method? Is the string returned from the db as you expected cause it could be your code returns an empty string and that's what you're displaying.

Comment: The text view is not getting display so I am unable to add or delete anything from it. hence I have not checked anything.

Comment: Well, your code changes the TextView text value to an empty string when the Activity gets create, that's probably why you're not seeing it?

Comment: But there are 2 text views one should then also be displayed but its also not getting displayed.

Comment: Then it's possibly something to do with your layout. Try to simplify it. Remove all your database stuff (comment out). Then simplify your UI to just have one text field, make sure it has some hardcoded text, make sure it's width and height wraps content, check if it appears. Then add the next item, position it and check it appears and so on. That might help you to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in Android a lot. Try changing the settings about where the buttons are placed. If a screen is 1080p but you developed it with a 480p screen, it will be huge. Try making the buttons scale by screen size.

Comment: This has happened for the first time with me I have made many test apps but never has it happened. Maybe this has to do with the sql lite part because I have not used it before and I have used dp so this would work for small screen too.

Comment: SQlite doesn't mess with the ui though. I think it's just a little code mess up. Try running it in a virtual machine and try messing with (deleting and re adding) ui elements. If all else fails, re code it again.